# Is there a way to pass data source connection string as a parameter to power bi embedded?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a pbix file that takes an Azure Storage account as a parameter and reads data from there accordingly. The next step is to be able to embed this powerbi dashboard on a webpage and let the end user specify the storage account. I see a lot of questions and answers surrounding passing in filter query parameters--this is different, we're trying to read from a completely different data source and not filtering on a static data source.

Another way to ask this question is: is there a way to embed powerbi template files, if not, is there a feature request somewhere we can upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

There is a reason to use filters in this case instead of parameters. Parameters are something that is part of the report itself. Each users that looks at your reports will get the same parameter values as the others. If one of them changes some parameter, this will affect all other users. Filters on the other hand, is something local for your session. You can filter the report the way you like, and this will not affect other users experience in any way.

You can't embed templates, because template is simply a state of the report on the disk. When you open it, it's not a template anymore, but becomes a report.

You can either combine the data from all of your data sources in a single report, adding one more column to indicate from where this data comes from, and then filter on this new column. Or create/modify ETL process (for example [dataflows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-dataflows-overview) can be used for this) to combine these data sources into a single one.